# Set up SSL client authentication with React JS in development mode using Express server for dev mode

Tags: reactjs, express, ssl, webpack, ca

When i use React Js with Node Js https library for get/post queries in **PRODUCTION** to backend server with keystore authentication from my react app with Self Signed CA - everything is Ok (ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/ca.crt')). Here is code bellow:

```
var options = {
    hostname: hostname,
    port: port,
    path: pathMethod,
    method: method,
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./ca.crt'),
    checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
        return undefined;
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': APPLICATION_JSON,
    },
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    agent: false,
    requestCert: true

};

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding(ENCODING_UTF8);

        res.on('data', function(result) {

            try {
                const obj = JSON.parse(result);
                resolve({
                    'httpStatus': PAGE_STATUS_200,
                    'token': obj.token,
                    'access': obj.access,
                    'userName': obj.userName,
                    'language': obj.language.toUpperCase(),
                });
            }
            catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
                resolve(resolve({ 'httpStatus': PAGE_STATUS_500 }));
            }

        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('No more data in response.');
        });
    });

    req.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(`problem with request: ${err.message}`);
        reject(err);
    });

    if (postData) {
        req.write(postData);
    }

    req.end();
});
```

But i have the problem, when i write code in **DEVELOPMENT**, because in the develompent i use DEV SERVER for hot redeploy, serving static files and other cute features and at this mode native Node Js module "fs" does not work('fs.readFileSync is not a function'-error). Also i was trying to use "raw-loader" for webpack for uploading CA-certificate and also used to this line:

```
node: {
    fs: "empty"
}
```

But unfortunately it not helped me. Also i tried use some proxy middleware, for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy:

```
const app = express()
app.use('/', proxy('https://127.0.0.1:8443', {
    proxyReqOptDecorator: function(proxyReqOpts, originalReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.ca =  [fs.readFileSync('./ca.crt')]
    proxyReqOpts.rejectUnauthorized = true
    proxyReqOpts.agent = false
    proxyReqOpts.requestCert = true
    proxyReqOpts.method = 'POST'
    proxyReqOpts.checkServerIdentity = function (host, cert) {return undefined;}
    return proxyReqOpts;
}
```

But CA certificate works unfortunately, only when i print URL directly in my browser and push enter. If i push button and perfom https query to the back-end server - it not works.

Maybe anybody know, how to set up SSL client authentication in development mode using Express server for development mode with some middleware or appropriate Webpack loader for uploading certificate, or other tricks?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing a

```
var fs=require('fs');
```

on the index.js ,the index file for the node server you have created

Comment: Yup, of course, i've imported fs and other necessary module in head, just at this question don't show all imported files (because that the question would not be too long).

Comment: Hi @alexis_druzik, did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @reactjs_user did you find solution to using mTLS on React.js client side application?